# eclipse.desktop launcher in /usr/share/applications locked in dash just launches eclipse, but the window is opened in another icon

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, eclipse

Ubuntu unity opens a new icon in dash every time i open eclipse, don't mind if i just execute it from the binary or if i created a desktop file.

I also reset unity without exit.

[image: imagereferredto]

Comment: Look in `~/.local/share/applications`, is there another .desktop file of eclipse?

Comment: There is only one desktop file:
pol@codingmachine:~$ ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep ecli
eclipse.desktop.

Also now... i don't see the icon thoug is in theory in favourites:
http://imgur.com/53mCm0F
pol@codingmachine:~$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
['unity://running-apps', 'application://google-chrome.desktop', 'application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://eclipse.desktop', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']
I once had eclipse installed from the repo, uninstalled and installed kepler from the web i supose it's involved though i reseted unity

Comment: a few silly questions, but what is the output of `which eclipse` (and how did you install it) and what is is the contents (Exec= line) of the desktop file?

Comment: I don‘t have the laptop right now, when i arrive at home i will run wich eclipse. However i installed it downloading from the oficial web and then extracting at /opt adding a symlink to /bin (/bin/eclipse) . Then i made the desktop file , in the exec line i put the following Exec=eclipse

Comment: I did the steps you mention, without an error, it runs under its own icon. I am curious to `which`, and the contents of your desktop file. Could you post it in the question? Did you ever have another version installed?

Comment: i have any command called wich and apt-get doesn't install it, 
Did you mean whereis ?
`pol@codingmachine:~$ whereis eclipse
eclipse: /usr/bin/eclipse /usr/bin/X11/eclipse`
And yes, i had installed the repo version of eclipse, and uninstalled it because of it was incompatible with egit, i supose that's the trouble, i installed it in my desktop succesfully too.

Comment: Nono `which` (you forgot the `h`, second character), as in: `$ which eclipse` [outputs] `/bin/eclipse`.  But looking at your output, it looks you have an old eclipse version installed still. /usr/bin/eclipse shouldn't be there the way you installed it.

Comment: my fault, no output anyway 
`pol@codingmachine:~$ which eclipse
pol@codingmachine:~$ `. 

So ... i should rename this topic and call it  how to remove eclipse completely in order to upgrade it.

Comment: what is the content of your desktop file? do you have an older version installed as well (see my edited comment above). We should remove some comments afterwards probably :) (if not all)

Comment: `[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse
Exec=eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Type=Application
Categories=IDE;Development`

Comment: I am pretty sure you still have an old version installed as well.. I also believe the references to the applications are messed up, hard to say what is exactly the situation. Terrible advice, but appropriate here I think: 1. remove (old)eclipse by SC or whatever, then 2. remove everything you installed from eclipse manually, including the link, then reinstall it from scratch. Let me know.

Comment: the old eclipse was uninstalled it time ago via SC... and then installed this version, never stayed togheter in the pc

Comment: I am afraid your whereis output suggests some parts were left :(

Comment: I just deleted the symlinks and the desktop file , installed it and removed it from the SC and make the symlinks again... just dont work , isnt apt get suposed to index what installs and erase it later, what a mess.

Comment: definitely, but `whereis` shouldn't mention `/usr/bin/eclipse` in your setup if it was "clean". It still doesn't work???

Comment: tried to install again, but this time not remove and instead purge and autoremove , no which or whereis output,reset unity and  download eclipse luna and install it again... the damm gmm_verify window thing still appears, also unity now do strange things like not map the super+(1-9) keyboard bindings.
I think it's time to format, i love linux for the hacks, however sometimes it's better a fresh start.
I would love to know what caused this mess, but i think it could be anything. 
Thanks anyway for the help

Comment: Last thing that jumped into my mind: what happens if you set the Exec= line to /opt/eclipse/eclipse? just curious.

Comment: Same thing , i tried too :s